# Under what conditions is a complete metric space compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $F$ denotes the set of all bounded functions $f: A \rightarrow [M_1,M_2]$ where $A= [x_1,x_2]$. Under the uniform norm, is the set $F$ compact?  If not, what are additional conditions under which $F$ will be compact?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A complete metric space is compact if and only if it is totally bounded, which means that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite covering by balls of radius $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think, the specific set $F$ given above satisfies this property?

Comment: @Abca No, I don't think it does, unless the endpoints are fixed.

Comment: Thank you Matt, can you elaborate on that please. I think I might be able to show that

Comment: Yes, $M_1,M_2$ and $x_1,x_2$ are fixed across all functions in the set F

Comment: @Abc Then I would guess that it's totally bounded. However I'm not going to make any attempt to prove it because I haven't touched this subject in years and may make an error that I don't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

With $x_1,x_2, M_1,M_2\in \Bbb R$ with $x_1<x_2$ and $M_1<M_2,$ and $\|g-f\|=\sup \{|g(x)=f(x)|:x\in [x_1,x_2]\}$:

Let $r=(M_2-M_1)/3.$

The open cover of $F$ by the set $\{B(f,r):f\in F\}$ of all open balls of radius $r$ has no finite sub-cover.

Proof: If $n\in \Bbb N$ and $ C =\{B(f_j, r): n\geq j\in \Bbb N\},$ let $\{y_j:n\geq j\in \Bbb N\}$ be a set of $n$ distinct points in $[x_1,x_2].$

There exists $g\in F$ such that  $g(y_j)\in [M_1,M_2]\setminus (-r+f_j(y_j),\,r+f_j(x_j)\,)$ for $1\leq j\leq n.$ Then $g \not \in \cup C$.

(Because $\|g-f_j\|\geq r$ for each $j,$ so $ g\not\in B(f_j,r)$ for each $j.$)

So $\cup C \ne F.$

Comment: Thank you, better late than never.